# LNK1169 caused by including a header more than once in separate cpp files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include, linker-errors

In my program, I am encountering LNK1169 and I don't see how this error could be caused considering the context.

units.h:

```
#ifndef UNITS_H
#define UNITS_H

namespace units {
    extern constexpr double N = 1.0;
};

#endif
```

A.h:

```
#pragma once
class A {
public:
    A();
};
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "units.h"

A::A() {

}
```

B.h:

```
#pragma once
class B {
public:
    B();
};
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"
#include "units.h"

B::B() {

}
```

ErrorTest.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    A* _a = new A();
    B* _b = new B();
    return 0;
}
```

Error Messages:

```
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  ErrorTest   C:\Users\---\source\repos\ErrorTest\x64\Debug\ErrorTest.exe 1
Error   LNK2005 "double const units::N" (?N@units@@3NB) already defined in A.obj    ErrorTest   C:\Users\---\source\repos\ErrorTest\ErrorTest\B.obj 1
```

Is there something immediately obvious that I'm missing? I'm certain I'm abiding by the one definition rule.

I tried ensuring I am following the one definition rule and changing the way I include units.h but the error is always the same. If I include units.h in more than one cpp, I will always get LNK1169.

Comment: Everything you showed is fine. There must be something wrong with your project, or something else you didn't show.

Comment: Remove the `extern` in `extern constexpr double N = 1.0;` If you're building in C++17 (or higher) mode then replace `extern` with `inline`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky That's the odd thing. The code above was made with an entirely new fresh project. It doesn't make sense for it to be a misconfiguration.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well that fixed it. Thanks! I was using c++ 17.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no problem here with `extern`, even using c++17.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I get the error with both GCC and Clang (both relatively recent). What compiler and linker are you using? Which version of it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Visual Studio 2022, MS compiler 19.30.30706 for x86,  Linker 14.30.30706.0. Using c++20.

Comment: @Jabberwocky release build? Maybe the compiler overlooks the multiple definitions if its storage has been optimized away. In any case it definitely *should* be marked `static` or `inline` rather than `extern`.

Comment: Marking it as extern and providing a definition makes no sense, I'd guess visual studio is ignoring the extern whilst gcc and clang are ignoring the constexpr. Not sure which is correct or if this code is simply non-standard

Comment: @PhantomPilot no difference between release and debug builds.

Comment: Because you added the `extern` keyword, then the definition will have external linkage. And that will lead to the variable being defined in all translation units that include the header file. If you remove the `extern` keyword it will have internal linkage (because of `constexpr`). As an alternative, don't define the variable in the header file, only declare it (keep the `extern` but remove the initialization, put definition (without `extern` but with initialization) in a single source file).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because when you compile `a.cpp`, you get units::N defined as part of the include.

Then when you compile `b.cpp`, you also get units::N defined as part of the include.  The include guard only applies at the preprocessing phase, but at this point you've already compiled a.cpp, and b.cpp, both of which included units.h.  Since you *defined* (as opposed to declared) N in both, that's probably what the linker is seeing as an error.

If you want to read up more on it, and since it looks like you're using VS, here's a link to `extern` documentation, and there's a specific mention of `extern constexpr` there.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that `extern constexpr double N = 1.0;` is a **definition** of a variable named `N` with ***external linkage*** since you've used `extern` keyword. So when this header file gets included by multiple source files, that variable gets defined multiple time and hence the error.

To **solve** this either remove the `extern` keyword so that `N` will have ***internal linkage*** or replace `extern` with `inline` if you're using c++17.